# Praying in front of the Aron HaKodesh

Tags: halacha, tefilla, ark-aron-kodesh

Sometimes I find myself in situations where I can only pray behind the Aron HaKodesh. Is there anything wrong with that according to Halacha?

I ask because seemingly Chazal wanted the Aron HaKodesh to be in front, and everybody praying towards it.

Comment: Your last sentence is not universally true.  I was in a Sephardic shul (in Mexico City) where the Aron HaKodesh was free standing, not in the eastern wall as is in Ashkenazic shuls and there were people on the other side who came around to the front as needed by the prayers.

Answer (score 2):

The Shulchan Aruch in Siman 94 states that wherever one is when they pray the should face Eretz Yisrael/Yerushalayim/Makom Hamikdash. Having an aron kodesh does not effect this halacha. As far as I recall the only change to the prayer service that would be effected by praying without the presence of an aron kodesh would be whether one lays their head on their arm during Nefilas Apaim or not.